# Desaturate a live UIView layer (not a UIImageView)

Tags: ios, uiview, uiappearance, tint

I'm wondering what would be the best way to desaturate a UIView—particularly, a UISliderView with custom appearance applied to it.  In iOS 7, the standard controls fade out their tint colors when another view appears over them (for example, a share sheet or UIAlertView), but since mine is built from UIImages, the tint property doesn't apply to it, and they remain saturated.
Is there a good, easy way to desaturate this, short of re-applying a new UIAppearance for it?  (If I were to go that route, would I even be able to animate the transition from colored images to greyscale ones?)

Thanks in advance!